# Flask-mail (python): Running out of application context error

Tags: python, email, flask, flask-mail

I am implementing flask-mail in our flask application but can't get rid of the app running out of context error. Any help would be appreciated. I have placed the mail_server params in the config file.

/app.py - app is instantiated in create_web_apis

```
def create_app(config):
"""Creates an instance of the app according to `config`

:param config: An instance of :class:`flask.config.Config`

:returns: The configured application. This can be passed to a WSGI
  container.

"""
app = create_web_apis()

app.config.update(config)
mail = Mail(app)
...
```

/emails.py

```
from flask import current_app
from flask.ext.mail import Mail, Message


mail = Mail(current_app) 

def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body, html_body):
    msg = Message(subject, sender = sender, recipients = recipients)
    msg.body = text_body
    msg.html = html_body
    mail.send(msg)
```

here is the full trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bin/run-tests", line 58, in <module>
test_suite = test_loader.loadTestsFromNames(args.tests)
File       "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 128, in loadTestsFromNames
suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 91, in loadTestsFromName
module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
File "/Users/tahsin/dev/restful_phollow/phollow/tests/test_external.py", line 16, in <module>
from phollow.emails import send_email
File "/Users/tahsin/dev/restful_phollow/phollow/emails.py", line 6, in <module>
mail = Mail(current_app) 
File "/Users/tahsin/dev/venv/phollow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 461, in __init__
self.state = self.init_app(app)
File "/Users/tahsin/dev/venv/phollow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 473, in init_app
app.config.get('MAIL_SERVER', '127.0.0.1'),
File "/Users/tahsin/dev/venv/phollow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
File "/Users/tahsin/dev/venv/phollow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
return self.__local()
File "/Users/tahsin/dev/venv/phollow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 26, in _find_app
raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')
```

Comment: Could you start with fixing indentation and providing full example. It is not clear what is going on inside `create_web_apis`. Also traceback suggest you are running some tests, right? So where is `test_external.py`? You should provide [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) if want to get an answer.

Comment: the test case in test_external just passes in the params for send_email. Sorry should have mentioned that.

Comment: It is hard to diagnose the problem without code that caused it. Nevertheless you can read my answer and it should give you the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide application context inside your test for example by using `app.test_request_context`. You can read more in [official docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/#faking-resources-and-context)

You can try this:

emails.py

```
from flask import current_app
from flask.ext.mail import Mail, Message

def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body, html_body):
    mail = Mail(current_app) 
    msg = Message(subject, sender = sender, recipients = recipients)
    msg.body = text_body
    msg.html = html_body
    mail.send(msg)
```

test.py

```
import unittest
from app import create_app
from flask.ext.mail import Message
from emails import send_email

class AppTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
       self.app = create_app()

    def test_mail(self):
        with self.app.test_request_context('/'):
            send_email("Hello",
                  sender="from@example.com",
                  recipients=["to@example.com"],
                  text_body='',
                  html_body='',
            )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**Note**:

If you create `Mail` instance in `app.py` don't repeat yourself in `emails.py`. Something 
like below should be sufficient:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app
```

test.py

```
import unittest
from app import create_app
from flask.ext.mail import Message

class AppTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
       self.app = create_app()

    def test_mail(self):
        with self.app.test_request_context('/'):
            self.app.mail.send(Message("Hello",
                  sender="from@example.com",
                  recipients=["to@example.com"]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

You can test both with DebuggingServer

`python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025`

Comment: thanks a lot for your input! Unfortunately I am still getting the error. I think it's current_app.mail.send(msg) that's the problem. Yes, I did make mail a member of the app.

Comment: I am wondering if it will be possible to create a sub-class for Mail in my api or pass in the mail object as a parameter. I am extremely new to Flask and python so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Right now even your `send_email` seems to be redundant. There is nothing what can't be handled by simple one-liner, so I would keep it simple.

Comment: but i am still not sure how i can solve my problem? It seems that I can't use current_app. I am not worried about redundancy at this moment as I'll add a lot more functionality once i get around the flask application issue.

Comment: thanks a lot for all your help! On a side note do you know if there is a way for me to make the the msg body (html), sub, rec as configurable params so that it is possible to change those things without updating the server